# Why does test-scoped setting not hold correct value?

Tags: scala, sbt

Scopes matters in sbt. And I'm completely OK with it. But there are also delegating rules that allows you build a hierarchical structure of settings. I'd like to use it to bring extra settings to more specific rules.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {
  val sourceExample = settingKey[Seq[String]]("example source for setting dependency")
  val targetExample = settingKey[Seq[String]]("example of a dependent setting")

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ Seq (
    sourceExample := Seq("base"),
    targetExample := "extended" +: sourceExample.value,
    sourceExample in Test += "testing"
  )
}
```

The example gives me unexpected output:

```
> show compile:sourceExample
[info] List(base)
> show test:sourceExample
[info] List(base, testing)
> show compile:targetExample
[info] List(extended, base)
> show test:targetExample
[info] List(extended, base)
```

I expect `test:targetExample` be `List(extended, base, testing)` not `List(extended, base)`. Once I've get the result I immediately figure out why exactly it works as shown. `test:targetExample` delegates from `*:targetExample` the calculated value but not the rule for calculating it in nested scope.

This behavior brings two difficulties for me writing my own plugin. I have extra work to define same rules in every scope as a plugin developer. And I have to memorize scope definitions of internal tasks to use it correctly as user.

How can I overcome this inconvenience? I'd like to introduce settings in *call-by-name* semantic instead of *call-by-value*. What tricks may work for it?

P.S. `libraryDependencies in Test` looks much more concise that using `% test`.

---

I should make clear that I perfectly understand that the sbt derives values just as it is described in documentation. It works as the creator intended it to work.

But why should I obey to the rules? I see them completely counter-intuitive. Sbt introduces inheritance semantic that actually works unlike how inheritance used to be defined. When you write

```
trait A { lazy val x : Int = 5 }
trait B extends A { lazy val y : Int = x * 2}
trait C extends A { override lazy val x : Int = 3 }
```

you expect `(new B with C).y` be 6, not 10. Knowing that it would be actually 10 allows you to use this kind of inheritance correctly but leaves your with desire to find more conventional means for implementing inheritance. You may even write your own implementation based on `name->value` dictionary. And you may proceed further according to the tenth rule of programming.

So I'm searching for a hack that would bring inheritance semantic in accordance with common one. As a start point I may suggest writing [command](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Extending/Commands.html) to scan all settings and push them from parents to children explicitly. And than invoke this command automatically each time sbt runs.

But it seems too dirty for me, so I'm curios if there is more graceful way to achieve similar semantic.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the *"incorrect"* value is that `targetExample` depends on `sourceExample` in `Compile` scope as in:

```
targetExample := "extended" +: sourceExample.value
```

Should it use `sourceExample` value from `Test` scope, use `in Test` to be explicit about your  wish as follows:

```
targetExample := "extended" +: (sourceExample in Test).value
```

Use `inspect` to know the dependency chain.

BTW, I strongly advise using `build.sbt` file for such a simple build definition.

Answer (score 0):

You could have default settings, and reuse it in different configurations as described in [Plugins Best Practices - Playing nice with configurations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#Playing+nice+with+configurations). I believe, this should give you a semantic similar to what you're looking for.

You can define your base settings and reuse it in different configurations.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object TestBuild extends Build {

  val sourceExample = settingKey[Seq[String]]("example source for setting dependency")
  val targetExample = settingKey[Seq[String]]("example of a dependent setting")

  override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ 
    inConfig(Compile)(basePluginSettings) ++
    inConfig(Test)(basePluginSettings ++ Seq(
      sourceExample += "testing" // we are already "in Test" here
    ))

  lazy val basePluginSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq (
    sourceExample := Seq("base"),
    targetExample := "extended" +: sourceExample.value
  )

}
```

PS. Since you're talking about writing your plugin, you may also want to look at the new way of writing sbt plugins, namely [AutoPlugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html), as the old mechanism is now [deprecated](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#Avoid+older++mechanism).

Comment: And what should I do if there are more settings? `libraryDependencies` may be used as example. It is not defined per Task for reason it is too cumbersome and realize custom inference mechanic. That `% test` part of dependency definition.

Comment: @ayvango I'm not sure if I get it correctly, but you could add settings which are not scoped for example as another `lazy val`, and add it to `settings` without scoping via `inConfig` method. However if you define it in `basePluginSettings` I guess it should also work, you just don't override it in a configuration